# There is a error on the third script line but i cant spot.

Tags: javascript

On my third script line, there's an error that I can seem to spot. Please if you can see what I cant, please let me know. Thanks for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <Script>

                        var x = 5;
                        var y = 10;
                        if ( x < y && y = 2 * x )
                                document.write(x);
                        else
                            document.write(y);

                </script>



        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe change  `y = 2 * x` to  `y === 2 * x`. One equals is assign, 3 is compare.

Comment: y == 2 * x sdsdsds

Comment: and what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't comparing with a single `=` you need to use `==` or `===` to compare values in a comparison check.

Change: `y = 2 * x`

To:     `y == (2 * x)` or `y === (2 * x)`

I put the parenthesis in there to make it easier to comprehend.

Comment: Thanks you for the help.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Please accept the answer when possible.